# Render HTML from REST API NodeJs, Express and EJS

Tags: node.js, express

I have an API with the method GET on mysite.com/api/posts  that returns a list of posts in JSON format

then I have this route mysite.com/posts which should render with EJS the Json from the /api/posts

How can achieve that with NodeJS Express ? 
How seniors NodeJS developers approach this?
Could you help me by throwing some code or maybe a NodeJS developer did something in GitHub?

My code looks like this:

**routes.js**

```
(...)

// GET route find all posts 
app.get('/posts', postsController.findAll); 

(...)
```

**postController.js**

```
(...)

findAll(req, res, next) {

    // This is the part that I am not sure, populate
    // data with the API results
    let data = app.get('/api/posts', apiPostsControllers.findAll)

    res.render('index', {
      page_layout: 'posts',
      page_title: 'Posts,'
      data: data
    });
  }

(...)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: google is your friend! this should be a good starting point: https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application

Comment: @PaoloMangia I think you didn't read what I said, sorry mate, but I know how to use Google and results like that ones are millons,  the link you sent me, they render the view straight away, but what I am trying to accomplish is to have and API that give me the JSON results and then render it, what I guess is I have to have 2 separate routes, but I dont know which one is the best approach to that. :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to post your data to that path . Then in request body you will get POST data, You can send this data to EJS template using res.render('path',{ data: [POSTdata] }); 
Then you will get all POST values in EJS template in data variable.
As you are exposing REST api in JSON format the you can use alternate approach of using Angularjs. so you can use angular http.get([RESTUrl]) and bind this data to HTML view